# OpenTelemetry with native-image

Tags: spring-boot, open-telemetry

I am already using OpenTelemetry in my Spring Boot 2.x apps with openetelemetry-java-instrumentation.

I am thinking about building these applications with native-image (actually testing spring-native).

Is there an alternative to use OpenTelemetry with native-image builds ?

Comment: Hey Oliver, coming back to your question. Were you able to find a solution? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The 1.20.0 of opentelemetry java (released Nov 11, 2022) have added graalVM hints, for native support. Make sure you use that version or above.
And be careful with the spring dependency BOM, it will want to bring in 1.19.0, so you may need to force 1.20+ if using Gradle.
https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java/releases/tag/v1.20.0

Helpful troubleshooting discussion on spring BOM using 1.19.0:
https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java/issues/5338